# Many joins, Here comes a table valued Function

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, grouping

I have lots of join (old school DB schema) and restrictions that returns values such as
Name, BookCreditsAwarded, BookCreditsAppliedThisTime, BookCreditsAvailable, DonorTrip, DonorName, DonorCreditTotal, DonorCreditAppliedThisTrip

Where BookCreditsAppliedThisTime is equal to SUM(DonorCreditAppliedThisTrip), everything is liked via the Name_ID and through another linked table ; donorTrip.

The report comes out with a line where columns from DonorTrip til DonorCreditAppliedThisTrip are null and the next X lines fills in the information.

I'm using Visual Studio for its reporting services that shows the extra X line, but when using SQL Server studio, it shows those extra lines always as null, making it hard to figure out if there are values!

Bottom line, I've added a Table Valued Function to it all but the group by is restraining me for I can't show the value without including the column in the group by clause. So I get the following result:
MrX, 0, 4000, 0, 320 as NewGuestCredit, GuestName, null, null, null..
MrX, 0, 4000, 0, 320 as NewGuestCredit, GuestName2, null, null, null..
[...]

instead of :
MrX, 0, 4000, 0, null, null, null, null, null..
[...]

Any idea? Or am I too unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am lucky enough to only require a DISTINC clause to it and do my join properly.